# Successful Heroku deployment, but only the header displays

Tags: heroku, deployment

I created a simple app built using React and a Rest api. It deployed successfully using Heroku, but when the app is opened it only displays the header. In addition, it displays the header as a full page; nothing else appears. When I run "npm start" to view the app in the IDE/browser, it is perfect. It is only when deployed that it fails to display the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**: I was able to resolve the issue. Hopefully, someone will benefit from what I have learned. When deploying to Heroku, make sure that you are deploying from the local main branch and not a feature branch. Cross-branch actions are not permitted with Heroku.